# How to prevent draggable handles in range slider form overlapping?

Tags: javascript, plugins, slider

I have to prevent dragable handles in range slider form overlapping . It is vanilla js plugin.

I tried to disable updating offset if the difference between two handles position is lower than 20px. It works sometimes, but the barrier is not precise. The movement is choppy when the handles are near to each other.The handle cannot be dragged immediately, but after few movements.

Here are the fragments of the plugin code:

```
// HELPERS
// map slider range to value range
Number.prototype.map = function(in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
    return (this - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
// round to nearest multiple
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(num) {
    var resto = this % num;
    if (resto <= (num / 2)) {
        return this - resto;
    } else {
        return this + num - resto;
    }
}


//EVENTS
var EVmove = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    EVmove = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    EVend = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';


document.addEventListener(EVmove, actions.move, false);
document.addEventListener(EVend, function() {
    return movebar = false;
}, false);
document.addEventListener(EVstart, function() {
    return movebar = true;
}, false);

var movebar = true;

// MOVE HANDLE
actions.move = function(event) {
    var clientX = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? event.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
    leftOffset = clientX - posX;

    // move handle bar
    if (movebar) {

        element.style.left = leftOffset + "px";
        var v = leftOffset.map(0, elWidth, 0, window.range); // 0

        var value = v.roundTo(step);
        output.innerHTML = value.toFixed(2);

        // prevent handles ovelaping
        if (vsOpts.range) {

            var diff = Math.abs(parseInt(handle1.offsetLeft) - parseInt(handle2.offsetLeft));

            if (diff < 20) {
                movebar = false;

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Just for the record, I strongly recommend against mutating the built-in objects such as Number, you can just write an ordinary function and call it instead

Comment: Thanks, i am aware that is not a good practice. However, it's not essential need for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by assigning position of the opposite handle as a limit position of the current handle

```
document.addEventListener(EVstart, function(event) {

    if (event.target.id == "vslider-handle1") {
        useHandle1 = true
    } else {
        useHandle1 = false
    }
    return movebar = true;
}, false);

}

handle1Limit=parseInt(handle2.offsetLeft);
handle2Limit=parseInt(handle1.offsetLeft);
handle1Pos=  parseInt(handle1.offsetLeft);
handle2Pos=  parseInt(handle2.offsetLeft);


if(useHandle1){ 

  if(handle1Pos>=handle1Limit){

   handle1.style.left = handle1Limit + "px";
   handle2.style.left = handle1Limit + "px";

  }

}
else{ 

  if(handle2Pos<=handle2Limit){

   handle2.style.left = handle2Limit + "px";
   handle1.style.left = handle2Limit + "px";

  }

}
```